# How to Logging In Zerodha Kite API without APIKey using C#

Tags: c#, access-token

I want to develop a Algo Tool. For this, I need to connect to Zerodha Kite API through code.
There are so many examples with python.
But I want to develop this with C#.

So I want to logging in Zerodha Kite API without APIKey. Only with "encToken" generted when logged in Zerodha Kite App in browser.

[image]

Can anybody help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically that encToken is enough for you login into zerodha for now.

check out this guys tutorial he has explained in few of his videos on how to connect to zerodha without APIkey.

https://www.youtube.com/c/TradeViaPython
https://github.com/TradeViaPython/Kite_Zerodha

when you go through the python code you can substitute the implementation in c#.